# How to setup CI/CD pipeline on AWS for dotnet website hosted on AWS EC2 (windows server 2019)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cicd

we have dotnet core website hosted on AWS EC2 (windows server 2019), now we want to setup CI/CD using AWS services only.

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link that can help you.  When you are the Create Deployment Group, chose EC2 on Premise. Make sure your agent is installed on your EC2 which it should be by default if your OS image is new.
[enter link description here](https://medium.com/codemonday/github-actions-for-ci-cd-with-ec2-codedeploy-and-s3-e93e75bf1ce0#:%7E:text=From%20AWS%20Console%2C%20navigate%20to%20CodeDeploy%20then%20Applications,Select%20role%20CodeDeployServiceRole%20that%20we%20just%20created%20above.)

Answer (score 0):

There is so much documentation around this area that a simple google search returns plethora of links. A simple place to start is the AWS documentation on DevOps https://aws.amazon.com/devops/

Then there is a specific AWS service for pipelines called (guess what) AWS CodePipeline
https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/

DotNet Core specific documentation is also covered by AWS https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/dotnet-core-cicd/

and if you ever want to move to AWS Lambda, then there's an article for that as well: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/automated-ci-cd-pipeline-for-net-core-lambda-functions-using-aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli/

Comment: Hello Hussain Mansoor, Thanks for reply..   I checked all documents but not able to find proper solution to configure CICD with EC2 and windows OS. Can you please point me to any documentation for CICD with EC2 and windows server OS

Comment: Instead of looking for specific use-case, 100% tailored to your need. Please try it first by yourself. There is lot of code in the above links which is enough to get anyone started. If you face any issues then share the code in new question